# Как автоматизировать добавление товаров на сайт?

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

Вопрос следующий: есть торговая площадка, которая не позволяет штатными методами массово добавлять товары на продажу. Возможно ли с помощью requests запросов это автоматизировать, или других библиотек на Python'e ? Добавлять товары из csv или json файла ?

Comment: Можно сделать что угодно, но сейчас в вопросе слишком мало деталей, чтобы можно было сказать что-то конкретное

Comment: Конкретизирую. Сайт shafa.ua. По Апи можно парсить его. А вот как в него грузить товар, не могу найти решения. Вообще, изучая документацию по requests и selenium, не нашел методов, как автоматизировать такие процессы на этом и похожих ресурсах, где нет штатных средств импорта/экспорта